# How to get the spelling of an unknown word by pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, spelling-pronunciations

I started to learn English by listening English news, from time to time I will come across some word that I have not learnt, with only pronunciation how can I get the spelling of the word?

When you learn Japanese, if you heard some Japanese word you don't know, by inputing the content you heard you can easily get the word. For example, assume `DA` is a Japanese word and its pronunciation is `ABCD`, by inputing `ABCD` you will get `DA`.

Comment: You can't. You just have to guess, or ask someone who knows the word. That's the problem with English spelling: it does a very poor job of representing English pronunciation. The better you get at English, the more likely you are to be able to make an educated guess at the spelling and actually be right; but even native speakers won't know that /bəˡloʊni/ is written _bologna_, or that /ˡvɪtl̩z/ is written _victuals_. In fact the reason they didn't is why the alternative spellings _baloney_ and _vittles_ are now so common.

Comment: Also, it's not easy at all to do the same in Japanese either. Even more difficult in many cases, in fact, especially names. If you meet someone whose name is _Hannawa_, what kanji should be used to write that? 半縄? 帆奈和? 樊那倭? Or perhaps something completely idiosyncratic like 島? Even outside names, monosyllabic words are all but impossible to guess. How should the word _jō_ be written, for example? 常, 城, 情, 縄, etc.?

Comment: Its so sad to hear that there's no easy way to guess in English. For the Japanese part, at least I can get a list of candidates and easy to guess according to the context.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be asking for resource recommendations rather than language usage.